# dynamic variable passing from database

Tags: php

we are generating php variable name directly linked with mysql rows output. here it is

now we have dynamic variable and we are doing base64 encoding of images

```
     ${'attachment_base64'.$row['id']} = base64_encode(file_get_contents($some_url));
```

now we want to pass this dynamically generated variable in while loop

```
     $image_part .= 'array(
              "name" => "'.$name.'",
              "data" => "$attachment_base64"
        ),';
```

but we are unable to pass dybanic name in data.

this part should be like this

```
       "data" => "$attachment_base641556588"
```

where 1556588 was dynamic id from database.

we cant use '.$row['id'].' as it will just append the data to base64 encoded data we want dynamic variable name to pass here

want to pass dynamic name in my array data part otherwise when i use this data after loop same image is passed in data part

generating this type of array from while loop data

```
     array(
              "name" => "ggggf",
              "data" => "$attachment_base64",
        ),
        array(
              "name" => "6800164880433",
              "data" => "$attachment_base64",
        ),
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Why do you have quotes around the call to `array()`?

Comment: want to pass dynamic name in my array data part otherwise when i use this data after loop same image is passed in data part

Comment: @Barmar generating this type of array from while data    array(
                  "name" => "ggggf",
                  "data" => "$attachment_base64",
            ),
   array(
                  "name" => "6800164880433",
                  "data" => "$attachment_base64",
            ),

Comment: Why are you concatenating strings instead of just pushing onto an array?

Comment: You really should get out of the habit of creating dynamic variable names. Anything you can do with that can be done more easily with an array.

Comment: @Barmar what is the alternative of my approach ??

Comment: `$image_array[] = array('name' => $name, 'data' => $attachment_base64[$row['id']]);`

Comment: @Barmar it will automatically add comma to next data and append all arrays ??

Comment: It's not a string, it's an array, there are no commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate `$row['id']` after the variable name prefix.

```
     $image_part .= 'array(
              "name" => "'.$name.'",
              "data" => "$attachment_base64'.$row['id'].'"
        ),';
```

But I strongly suggest that you change from dynamic variable names to associative arrays.

Comment: i am idiot no 1. i have tested same thing but  was writing some other data and thinking it was not working, it works thanks